# Need help with my report (rdlc)

Tags: report

In my report there is a table and a line.

the table is showing rows of data from my DB.

I want to know how you could make the table size commensurate with the line (make the length of the line is equal to the length of the table)

I set the property "RepeatWith" in the line properties to the table in my report, but this isn't working because this will only work if the data region spans multiple pages.

http://i40.tinypic.com/14o6n1c.png

In this photo the lind size is fixed, I want a way to make along the line equal to the volume of data in the table

How I can do that?

Thanks in Adv

Comment: It's not clear whether the line is horizontal or vertical and also where it is position in relation to the table?

Comment: the line is horizontal and I want this line to get bigger in length while data is being generate by report

Answer (score 0):

Ok! The best part is while designing the report, when you place the table and set its length, it will remain fix in the report no matter what data is. Rest once you have placed your table you can also place the line just beneath it of the same length.